SEGV in c++ std::set erase
I  am getting segmentation fault in c++ std::set erase function. I don't know the reason of SEGV.  please check the code below and help me know the reason of this SEGV.
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  std::set<int> myset;

  // insert some values:
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i*10);  // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

  myset.erase (40);

  std::set<int> myset2;
  myset2.insert(70);
  myset2.insert(90);
  myset.erase (myset2.begin(), myset2.end());   //SEGV  coming in this line

  std::cout << "myset contains:";
  for (it=myset.begin(); it!=myset.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}


I did google search but could not find solution.

The iterators passed to erase must be from the same container that erase is called upon.

do you want to remove all elements in myset from myset2 ?

It is unclear what you think myset.erase (myset2.begin(), myset2.end()); should do.

myset.erase (myset2.begin(), myset2.end());

you are passing iterators of myset2, despite the container being  myset.
use std::erase_if(myset,predicate) or
generate a new set containing the difference using std::set_difference instead

I'd say std::remove_if() instead of std::remove_copy_if(). OP only wants to remove elements that matches, not to copy the others (if any).

@Fareanor set returns const iterators, which makes my answer incorrect regarding remove_copy_if and your suggestion regarding remove_if, since they simply do not work with std::set

Indeed, std::remove and stuff reorder the elements inside the container, which is not allowed with set/map families.

Assuming you want to remove the values in set2 from set1.
The way to do this in C++ (C++20) is like this:
Just remember using the standard library you can often program
in a way where you don't have to write loops (or use iterators) yourself.
#include <set>
#include <algorithm> // include for std::erase_if (C++20)
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // sets can be initialized directly (if you want to)
    std::set<int> set1{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
    std::set<int> set2{20,70};
    
    // predicate is a lambda expression 
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
    // these are often used togheter with functions from
    // the standard library
    // this predicate returns true if value can be found in set2
    auto predicate = [&](const int value)
    { 
        return set2.contains(value);
    };

    // now remove all elements from set1 that match
    // the predicate (you can also directly write
    // a lambda instead of putting it in a local variable first)
    std::erase_if(set1,predicate);

    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
    for(const auto& value : set1)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
}


I don't follow the development of the standards too closely, and uniform container erasure flew under my radar. But it's so good.

@sweenish The thing is there is so much standard library it is hard to keep track of. I too learn things here I didn't know where in there. I think that's part of the fun, helping people and learning at the same time.
